# Why does ArrayAdapter lose order whenever I try to override getView method?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, listactivity

Consider the following example, the order of the list items is correct just before overriding getView() method. Whenever I override it to get some extra work done (not shown in the example) the order of the items becomes a real mess. I scroll down to see a number then I scroll up to see the same number again. What is the cause of that strange behavior and how can I fix it?

```
package com.staticlist;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    String[] items = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16",
            "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33",
            "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.main, items));
    }
}

class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public MyListAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, int main, String[] items) {
        super(mainActivity, main, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;

        if (convertView == null) {
            row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: use ViewHolder in ArrayAdapter, its a good practice

Comment: You are using the ViewHolder concept wrong. Views will be recycled with the ViewHolder-pattern. This means when your `convertView != null`, that you take an existing ViewHolder for your next row. This existing holder already has a number assigned.. To solve your problem and keep your list in sync with your datasource, you should add something like `row.setText(items[position]);` after your if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

due to you not creating the new view and using old one when you scroll down (at that time convertView will not null)

try this way it will come right

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
```

You need to do this (use convertview here) as ArrayAdapter already have logic for same

from widget/[ArrayAdapter.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mResource);
    }

    private View createViewFromResource(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent,
            int resource) {
        View view;
        TextView text;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
```

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to add following if you using Custom ArrayAdapter.

```
adapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(lhs) == Integer.parseInt(rhs))
                    return 0;
                else if (Integer.parseInt(lhs) > Integer.parseInt(rhs))
                    return 1;
                else
                    return -1;
            }
        });
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```